# How to encode message for telegram bot correctly for using special symbols?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, urlencode

I need to send notification into my telegram bot. For this im using next function:

```
const sendTgMessage = (msg) => {
  return axios
    .post(
      `https://api.telegram.org/bot${
        config.telegram.token
      }/sendMessage?chat_id=${
        config.telegram.chat
      }&parse_mode=MarkdownV2&text=${encodeURI(msg)}`
    )
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(' ~ file: sendTgMessage.js:8 ~ ).then ~ res:', res)
    })
}
```

Below is the message:

```
 const tgMessage = `this is test -#.:; this is text after symbols`
```

If my message contains symbols like '-', '#', etc it cant be send and my axios getting error. I cant understand why, in case that i'm already encoding it with encodeURL func.?

Axios error

```
{
    "message": "Request failed with status code 400",
    "name": "AxiosError",
    "stack": "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:287534:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:286210:66)",
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "adapter": "xhr",
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": {},
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
        },
        "method": "post",
        "url": "https://api.telegram.org/***hiddenapikey***/sendMessage?chat_id=***hiddenid***&parse_mode=MarkdownV2&text=this%20is%20test%20-#.:;%20this%20is%20text%20after%20symbols"
    },
    "code": "ERR_BAD_REQUEST",
    "status": 400
}
```

Comment: ooookay, I deleted my answer since you are still getting the error. However, you _must_ use `encodeURIComponent` instead of `encodeURI`. Otherwise, everything after `#` will not be sent at all. But why you're getting 400 from server I have no idea. Does it work for a message without `#` or `-`?

Comment: "Bad Request: can't parse entities: Character '#' is reserved and must be escaped with the preceding '\'"

I need function to escape all symbols like # . - etc

Comment: so if I understand this right this error comes from your server. And it seems saying that `#` inside of message should be _additionally_ prepended with `\`` or otherwise server tries to parse it... a command? a hashtag? I propose to replace `#` with `\#` and then to wrap with encodeURIComponent